# TypeError: c is not a constructor Exception is thrown during inherit from Rally.example.BareMetalChart and Rally.ui.chart.Chart classes

Tags: javascript, rally

I'm trying to build Chart using rallydev examples but unfortunately, TypeError: c is not a constructor Exception is thrown:

```
Error: success callback for Deferred transformed result of Deferred transformed result of Deferred threw: TypeError: c is not a constructor
at eval (eval at getInstantiator (sdk-debug.js:5720), <anonymous>:3:8)
at Object.instantiate (sdk-debug.js:5692)
at Object.create (sdk-debug.js:2303)
at constructor._createApp (sdk-debug.js:225510)
at constructor._launchAppInViewport (sdk-debug.js:225417)
at sdk-debug.js:225374
at constructor._loadTimeboxScope (sdk-debug.js:225505)
at sdk-debug.js:225373
at constructor.<anonymous> (sdk-debug.js:225280)
at constructor.<anonymous> (sdk-debug.js:10091)
```

However, it happens during inherit from `Rally.example.BareMetalChart` and `Rally.ui.chart.Chart` classes only.

Everything works as expected if i do inheritance from `Rally.example.StandardReport` class.

If anyone faced this the same issue and solved it, i would appreciate any help.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I just tested it and it worked for me...  Are you using the 2.1 example here? https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/example/bare-metal-chart

That error sounds like it can't find your app class.  This is usually caused by a mismatch between your js files and your config.json file.  Are you using rally app builder?  Usually all that is required is to make sure the class defined in your App.js matches the className specified in the config.json file and making sure App.js is included in the javascripts section.  Then just rebuild and you should be good to go.

Or, if you're just directly working on that html file from the example, did you do something to change the class name there?  Just make sure that the class created with Ext.define is then referenced by the call to Rally.launchApp down at the bottom and you should be good to go.